# How to extract the nth column of csv file with condition in Linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a large zip csv.gz file with three columns seperated by '|' like this:

```
"s"|"1"|"fgg"
"h"|"6"|"kjh"
"kjxcz"|"10"|"kj"
```

I would like to extract the lines in which the value of the second column is more than 5.

I already know how to extract the second column itself but do not know how to put condition and yet extract the whole line.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you have a zip archive which contains multiple csv files or a single csv file which has been gzipped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of `zcat`, `awk` can do it:

```
zcat file.gz | awk -F'[|"]' '$5>5'
```

Output:

```
"h"|"6"|"kjh"
"kjxcz"|"10"|"kj"
```

I'm using either `|` or `"` as the field separator, which makes it easy to access the numeric value of field 2 without the quotes. Then I'm checking whether the value is greater than 5. `awk` prints the current line if the condition is true.

You can solve it even more elegant using `gawk`. `gawk` support the `FPAT` variable (*field pattern*) which allows you to define how a field looks like rather being restricted to specify the delimiter. A field in our case is a sequence of non `"` and non `|` characters, which gives us:

```
zcat a.csv.gz | gawk '$2>5' FPAT='[^"|]+'
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. The first one works perfect but the solution with gawk is also giving numbers below five and I am guessing because the number is somehow a sting and this is not taken into account in the second solution.

Comment: The second solution is especially meant to prevent from this - elegantly. Can you show the input data leads to fail the second solution?

Comment: I am only getting the ones that are smaller or equal to five

Comment: I meant can you show the input data that leads to the error. If you try my command with input data you posted in the question it does not behave like that.

Comment: Awk is cool when used properly and simply. (It gets unreadble very soon.) The most cool feature is using booleans instead of *if-then*'s, like this: `cat the.csv | awk -F'[,"]' '($2~/[0-9]+/ && $3~/F[0-9]+/) || (!$2 && !$3)'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple column read loop to gather the information you need.

```
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 ; do
    if [ "$col2" > 5 ] ; then
        echo "$col1|$col2|$col3"
    fi
done < my_file.csv
```

This should do what you want to do, though it might be smarter to use built-in functions if you're looking for efficiency. There is usually one for every occasion.

Comment: I think you mean to `>` instead of `==`, because OP wants to _extract the lines in which the value of the second column is more than 5_.

Comment: @serenesat Woops, yes, my bad.